# StaticAliasToBeanResultTransformer

Tags: hibernate, search, hibernate-search

I am using hibernate search 1.1. I want to apply ResultTransformer operation post query to match the targeted data structure.

But i cannot be able to find that class(StaticAliasToBeanResultTransformer) in the **hibernate search** jar. Where can i find this class?.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

do you mean;

org.hibernate.transform.AliasToBeanResultTransformer?
If so this is included in the main hibrenate jar included in the distro.

[See javadocs](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/transform/AliasToBeanResultTransformer.html)

Comment: I am not using org.hibernate.transform package for this.
Below code is used in my project.

org.hibernate.search.FullTextQuery query = s.createFullTextQuery( luceneQuery, Book.class );
query.setProjection( "title", "mainAuthor.name" );

query.setResultTransformer( 
    new StaticAliasToBeanResultTransformer( BookView.class, "title", "author" ) 
);
List<BookView> results = (List<BookView>) query.list();
for(BookView view : results) {
    log.info( "Book: " + view.getTitle() + ", " + view.getAuthor() );
}


Thanks,